# Hibernate select with where

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have this [kind of tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hpg16.png)

My mapped classes look like this:

User

```
@Entity
    @Table(name = "user")
    public class User implements Serializable {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;
    
        @Column(name = "login", nullable = false)
        private String login;
    
        @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
        private String password;
    
        @Column(name = "email", nullable = false)
        private String email;
    
        @Column(name = "first_name")
        private String firstName;
    
        @Column(name = "last_name")
        private String lastName;
    
        @Column(name = "active", columnDefinition = "boolean default true")
        private boolean active;
    
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
        private UserRole userRole;
```

UserRole

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_role")
public class UserRole {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    public UserRole() {
    }
```

If I want to select all users with specific role I can do it like this with SQL `select * from user where role_id=1`.

The question is: Is there other briefer way to do it using my mapped classes and built-in Hibernate functions?

Thanks.

Comment: By "briefer" you mean shorter than the 26 char query?

Comment: you can use HQL like this: "from User u where u.userRole.id = 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the relation bi-directional by adding

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userRole")
private List<User> users;
```

in UserRole. Then it's a simple matter of fetching the UserRole in question and iterate users.

Comment: Thanks. Guess that's the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can use Hibernate criteria query since that seems more readable :

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(User.class);
cr.add(Restrictions.like("role_id", "1"));
List results = cr.list();
```